# Serving Discord bot and web requests simultaneously

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, discord.py

I am currently building a Flask application where I use the python discord API to listen to commands and return simple messages.

```
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", description="Bot")

    @bot.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send('%s PONG' % ctx.message.author.mention)

    bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

At the same time, I am serving a webpage at '/' but when I try to go onto the webpage, the page just hangs. I launch my flask application using gunicorn with the command "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --chdir application/site/ main:app --reload --log-level=DEBUG" and in the output, I get

```
    [2019-08-26 23:17:04 -0400] [50370] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
    [2019-08-26 23:17:05 -0400] [50370] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
    [2019-08-26 23:17:05 -0400] [50370] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (50370)
    [2019-08-26 23:17:05 -0400] [50370] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    [2019-08-26 23:17:05 -0400] [50373] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 50373
    [2019-08-26 23:17:05 -0400] [50370] [DEBUG] 1 workers
    [2019-08-26 23:17:08 -0400] [50373] [INFO] Logged in as Discord Bot 603846646383509504
    [2019-08-26 23:17:35 -0400] [50370] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:50373)
    [2019-08-26 23:17:35 -0400] [50373] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 50373)
    [2019-08-26 23:17:35 -0400] [50374] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 50374
    [2019-08-26 23:17:37 -0400] [50374] [INFO] Logged in as Discord Bot 603846646383509504
```

The discord bot works fine but loading the webpage does not. Am I missing something for my flask application to serve both requests at the same time or is this expected behavior?

Comment: `client.run` is blocking, which might be causing your webpage to not load. See here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.run

Comment: ah got it. thanks for the API reference! @Benjin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue you are having is because both the Flask app and the Discord bot are both synchronous and Python by default can handle only one synchronous process at a time.

Fortunately, you can use the `threading` library in Python to put the Flask app into a thread and leave the Discord bot function running to handle events.

See this Github gist for an example of how to do this: https://gist.github.com/crrapi/c8465f9ce8b579a8ca3e78845309b832

Comment: this not found,

Comment: Unfortunately the author took down the gist and I was unable to make a copy of it. You can see what I wrote here, it could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61741166/1892651